# How can I combine two search operators in the Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: search, outlook-on-the-web, attachment

Blank space doesn't seem to work. E.g. when I use `size:large hasattachment:true` I see no results, Whereas both `size:large` and `hasattachment:true` used alone return results that are similar (i.e., I see emails which are both in `size:large` and `hasattachment:true`)

Comment: I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: If anyone has any idea, welcome!